# BigTable & gRPC - Memory Leak, How to Resolve?

Tags: python, grpc, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm having issues writing to BigTable from Cloud Functions.

The memory consumption of a machine goes up, so I suspect there is a memory leak somewhere.

BigTable Settings:

```
cbt createtable test
cbt createfamily test data
```

Minimal Code:

`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "google_auth.json"`

```
import datetime
import random
import sys
import os
import string

from google.cloud import bigtable
from google.api_core.retry import Retry

def insert_row(project_id, instance, table, row_key, column_family_id, data):
    client_bigtable = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)

    # Generate an instance so that we can put our features into BigTable
    instance = client_bigtable.instance(instance)
    table = instance.table(table)

    # We need to keep a list of table changes into a list, then perform a mutation to update all changes.
    rows = []

    # Create a timestamp, this is required to set a cell
    time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    for key, value in data.items():
        row = table.row(row_key)
        # If we cannot convert to string, and this happens with unicode values, we need to encode the string
        # into unicode first
        row.set_cell(
            column_family_id=column_family_id.encode(),
            column=key.encode(),
            value=str(value).encode("unicode-escape"),
            timestamp=time
        )
        rows.append(row)
    table_mutation = table.mutate_rows(rows, retry=Retry(deadline=1200))

    # If the code is not 0, then there is an issue
    if any([True if i.code != 0 else False for i in table_mutation]):
        logging.error(f"Function Name: {insert_row.__qualname__}, Function Locals: {locals()}")
        raise RuntimeError("BigTable table mutation error")`
```

```
data = {
    ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=15)):''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=15)) for _ in range(100)
}

while True:
    insert_row(
        project_id="user-tracking-228117",
        instance="analytics",
        table="test",
        row_key=f"{random.randint(0, sys.maxsize)}_{datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f')}",
        column_family_id="data",
        data=data
    )
```

Memory Consumption:

```
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1118552 128968  21952 S   2.3  0.4   0:04.99 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1118552 129844  21952 S   2.0  0.4   0:05.05 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1118552 129968  21952 S   1.0  0.4   0:05.08 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1118552 130780  21952 S   1.6  0.4   0:05.13 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119116 132212  21952 S   9.2  0.4   0:05.41 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119116 134008  21952 S   4.3  0.4   0:05.54 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119116 134944  21952 S   2.6  0.4   0:05.62 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119116 137924  21952 S   6.6  0.4   0:05.82 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119116 138536  21952 S   1.7  0.4   0:05.87 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119116 139988  21952 S   3.0  0.4   0:05.96 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119096 141768  21952 S  11.2  0.4   0:06.30 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119096 144140  21952 S   4.6  0.4   0:06.44 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119096 145140  21952 S   2.6  0.4   0:06.52 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119096 148648  21952 S   7.6  0.5   0:06.75 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119096 148920  21952 S   0.7  0.5   0:06.77 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119096 149828  21952 S   2.3  0.5   0:06.84 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119608 152796  21952 S  12.2  0.5   0:07.21 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119608 154692  21952 S   4.6  0.5   0:07.35 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119608 155448  21952 S   1.6  0.5   0:07.40 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119608 156656  21952 S   2.6  0.5   0:07.48 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119608 157724  21952 S   2.6  0.5   0:07.56 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119608 160796  21952 S   6.9  0.5   0:07.77 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1119608 161616  21952 S   1.7  0.5   0:07.82 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185468 163896  21952 S  12.8  0.5   0:08.21 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185476 167612  21952 S   7.6  0.5   0:08.44 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185476 170552  21952 S   6.6  0.5   0:08.64 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185804 173848  21952 S  13.5  0.5   0:09.05 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185804 173848  21952 S   0.3  0.5   0:09.06 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185804 176724  21952 S   6.6  0.5   0:09.26 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185804 180588  21952 S   8.5  0.6   0:09.52 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1185804 181524  21952 S   2.3  0.6   0:09.59 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183228  21952 S  12.5  0.6   0:09.97 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183228  21952 S   0.7  0.6   0:09.99 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183276  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.00 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183296  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.01 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183332  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.02 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183436  21952 S   0.7  0.6   0:10.04 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183516  21952 S   0.7  0.6   0:10.06 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183616  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.07 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183656  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.08 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183656  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.09 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183680  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.10 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183708  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.11 python3.6
> 34755 ubuntu    20   0 1186116 183728  21952 S   0.3  0.6   0:10.12 python3.6
```

Memory: 128968 ==> 183728

After running a while, I'm running into an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_Rendezvous                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in next(self)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in __next__(self)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py in _next(self)

_Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'Too many open files'), ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'system lib'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1548443075.831642536","description":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'Too many open files'), ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'system lib'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]","file":"src/core/lib/security/credentials/plugin/plugin_credentials.cc","file_line":82,"grpc_status":14}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9f1f73192607> in <module>
     12         row_key=f"{random.randint(0, sys.maxsize)}_{datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%f')}",
     13         column_family_id="data",
---> 14         data=data
     15     )
     16 

<ipython-input-1-e79f91f922f9> in insert_row(project_id, instance, table, row_key, column_family_id, data)
     34         )
     35         rows.append(row)
---> 36     table_mutation = table.mutate_rows(rows, retry=Retry(deadline=1200))
     37 
     38     # If the code is not 0, then there is an issue

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/table.py in mutate_rows(self, rows, retry)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/table.py in __call__(self, retry)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, deadline, on_error)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigtable/table.py in _do_mutate_retryable_rows(self)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in next(self)

~/python3_virtualenv/python3_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: [('system library', 'fopen', 'Too many open files'), ('BIO routines', 'BIO_new_file', 'system lib'), ('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_load_cert_crl_file', 'system lib')]
```

I think the problem is the gRPC client.

One of the problem from Cloud Functions is that all the objects are not persistent, so there will clients that opens per each write request, but since the gRPC client is not released, the memory consumption is still used under that instance. However, since the gRPC client does not close, is there a way to forcefully close the gRPC client that is used under BigTable?

Comment: There's a related question on Github: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7208.

Comment: @SolomonDuskis You can reuse the BigTable client between invocations, but you don't know when the client gets cleaned up. So you would need to check and create client when it's gone. Which is a lackluster solution because now it would be hard to unit test. I think the better solution is to close the client and free resources.

Comment: Regardless you'd probably see better performance if you pulled the client creation outside of the insert_row function. Passing in client_bigtable would be a far safer option. The client should handle all underlying grpc connections for you and not need to be recreated for every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to close the client with the following code. It was introduced in pull request https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/6630.

```
client.table_data_client.transport.channel.close()
```